# Not getting reputation for upvote in case of answer is accepted

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history, daily-reputation-limit

I just noticed that I am not getting any reputation for few of the answers. And my guess is the answers which got recently accepted on Stack Overflow, upvote reputation is missing for those. Below is the screen shot. Are there any changes in the rule for awarding reputation? Or, I am missing something here?

**Update**: As per answer by Gothdo, that I have reached reputation limit. Then I have few questions:

1. If my reputation limit is exceeded, then why my dashboard is showing 247?
2. It should be missing from most recent entries, but why it is missing in random order?

[image]

Comment: You hit the rep cap.

Comment: What is rep cap?

Answer (score 5):

You hit the daily rep cap. From [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.